# Upon following setup instructions for Vue GWT, IntelliJ IDEA doesn't process e.g. @Component annotations

Tags: gwt, vue-gwt

(NOTE: this question is self-answered [Q&A-style](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), however please feel free to add and expand on my answer.)

I started experimenting with [Vue GWT](https://github.com/VueGWT/vue-gwt) and followed the general setup instructions as well as the ones specific to [IntelliJ IDEA](https://vuegwt.github.io/vue-gwt/guide/project-setup.html#intellij). IDEA, however, refused to process my `@Component` annotation (e.g. to generate the factory class for my component).

Answer (score 0):

My answer applies if you use Maven and have used IDEA's Maven project import when opening your project.

I found that I had to add the following to the project's `pom.xml`, an idea adapted from [MapStruct setup](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/ide-support/#intellij-idea):

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <!-- For IntelliJ IDEA to process Vue GWT annotations. -->
      <annotationProcessors>
        <annotationProcessor>com.axellience.vuegwt.processors.VueGwtProcessor</annotationProcessor>
      </annotationProcessors>
      ...
    </configuration>
    ...
  </plugin>
<plugins>
```